# Accessing URL parameters in Oracle Forms / OC4J

Tags: oracle, forms, url, parameters, oracleforms

How do I access parameters passed into an Oracle Form via a URL.
Eg  given the url:

> http://example.com/forms90/f90servlet?config=cust&form='a_form'&p1=something&p2=else

This will launch the 'a_form' form, using the 'cust' configuration, but I can't work how (or even if it's possible) to access p1 (with value of 'something') p2 (with value of 'else')

Does anyone know how I can do this? (Or even if it is/isn't possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within Forms you can refer to the parameters p1 an p2 as follows:

- :PARAMETER.p1
- :PARAMETER.p2

e.g.

```
if :PARAMETER.p1 = 'something' then
   do_something;
end if;
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Tony

That was one part of the problem.

The other needed part I eventually found on oracle.com was the url structure. After all the forms90 parameters (config etc), you need to supply an "otherparams" parameter supplying your parameters as a parameter to that. (parameters seperated by '+': eg

> http://server.com/forms90/f90servlet?config=test&otherparams=param1=something+param2=else

Thanks